# Illegal Characters in Path for XSLT Tranformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am writing an XSLT transformation to translate a XML credit report.

When I run the following code I am getting "Illegal Characters in Path" error.  Not sure what I am missing.  I want this method to return a HTML string.

I have tested the XSLT transform on the XML and it works.  This code fails on the transform.Load function with the "Illegal Characters in Path" error.

What am I missing here?

```
    private string FormatCreditReport(string inputXml)
    {
        var xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        var webRootPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
        var path = webRootPath
                   + "XSLT_Stylesheets"
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                   + "CreditReportTransform.xslt";
        var xsltTemplate = File.ReadAllText(path);

        xsltTransform.Load(xsltTemplate);

        StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml)))
        {
            xsltTransform.Transform(reader, null, results);
        }
        return results.ToString();
    }
```

XSLT Document:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

  <html>
    <body>

      <table border ="1">

        <tr>
          <th><h2>Credit File</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>File Since Date</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/FileSinceDate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date of Last Activity</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/DateOfLastActivity"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date of Request</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/DateOfRequest"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr></tr>

        <tr>
          <th><h2>Subject</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/Subject/LastName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>


  </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You cannot use Xml methods on html.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was bad and posted this question a second time, but someone was able to give me an answer so here it is....

```
    var xsltTemplate = File.ReadAllText(path);
    xsltTransform.Load(xsltTemplate);
```

should have been

```
    xsltTransform.Load(path);
```

and all is perfect.