# Illegal Characters in Path when loading XSLT document

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating a method to return an HTML string as the result of an XSLT transformation.

When I run the following code I am getting Illegal Characters in Path error on the following line:  `xsltTransform.Load(xsltTemplate)`.

Note I have tested the XSLT transform via another method and it works.

```
private string FormatCreditReport(string inputXml)
{
    var xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    var webRootPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
    var path = webRootPath
               + "XSLT_Stylesheets"
               + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
               + "CreditReportTransform.xslt";
    var xsltTemplate = File.ReadAllText(path);

    xsltTransform.Load(xsltTemplate);

    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml)))
    {
        xsltTransform.Transform(reader, null, results);
    }
    return results.ToString();
}
```

XSLT Document:

```
  <table border ="1">

    <tr>
      <th><h2>Credit File</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>File Since Date</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/FileSinceDate"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Last Activity</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/DateOfLastActivity"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of Request</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/CreditFile/DateOfRequest"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>

    <tr>
      <th><h2>Subject</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EfxTransmit/EfxReport/USConsumerCreditReports/USConsumerCreditReport/USHeader/Subject/LastName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Personal insults and unnecessary commentary are not appropriate here. I've removed that content from your post. Please visit the behavior section of the [help] to learn about appropriate conduct here.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138738/illegal-characters-in-path-for-xslt-tranformation

Comment: I apologize, I just am trying to figure this out and the response I got from that individual  was no help because they did not bother to fully read the question and I wanted to ensure that he did not weigh in again.  I will not repeat it.  I now see and understand the Flag system and will use from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call File.ReadAllText(path). Just pass the fully qualified file path as follows:

```
'var xsltTemplate = File.ReadAllText(path);
xsltTransform.Load(path);
```